# What does "$<$<CONFIG:Debug>:Release>" mean in cmake?

Tags: cmake

In [buildem_cmake_recipe.cmake](https://github.com/willyd/caffe-builder/blob/master/cmake/buildem_cmake_recipe.cmake), I saw an expression:

```
    externalproject_add_step(${_name} BuildOtherConfig
                        COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} --build ${BINARY_DIR} --config "$<$<CONFIG:Debug>:Release>$<$<CONFIG:Release>:Debug>" --target INSTALL
                        DEPENDEES install
                        )
```

What does the `$<$<CONFIG:Debug>:Release>$<$<CONFIG:Release>:Debug>` mean here?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

That's a CMake [generator expression](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html). You can follow the link for a full discussion of what these are and what they can do. In short, it's a piece of text which CMake will evaluate at generate time (when it's done parsing all CMakeLists and is generating the buildsystem); it can evaluate to a different value for each configuration.

The one you have there means roughly this (pseudo-code):

```
if current_configuration == "Debug"
  output "Release"
if current_configuration == "Release"
  output "Debug"
```

So, if the current configuration is Debug, the whole expression will evaluate to `Release`. If the current configuration's Release, it will evaluate to `Debug`. Notice that the step being added is called "BuildOtherConfig," so this inverted logic makes sense.

---

How it works, in a little more detail:

```
$<CONFIG:Debug>
```

This will evaluate to a `1` if the current config is `Debug`, and to a `0` otherwise.

```
$<1:X>
```

Evaluates to `X`.

```
$<0:X>
```

Evaluates to an empty string (no value).

Putting it together, we have `$<$<CONFIG:Debug>:Release>`. When the current config is `Debug`, it evaluates like this:

```
$<$<CONFIG:Debug>:Release>
$<1:Release>
Release
```

When the current config is not `Debug`, it evaluates like this:

```
$<$<CONFIG:Debug>:Release>
$<0:Release>
```

Comment: if I ask for Debug, it gives me Release...do you mind comment on this logic as well...lol. Thanks~

Comment: @davidshen84 Expanded, both to explain the inversion and to illustrate the expansion a bit better.

Comment: Where does the value of `CONFIG` come from? It seems like it's related to `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` but it doesn't seem to respond to it directly? Setting it with `-DCONFIG=Release` doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: It looks like it comes from [CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.17/variable/CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE.html), also note that [you can't use `message` to print out generator expressions](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html#debugging), something like `file(GENERATE OUTPUT ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/output.txt CONTENT "CONFIG is $<CONFIG>")` can be used though (it will put a file named output.txt in your build directory with the value of that expression).

Comment: @jrh The `CONFIG` used in this answer is not a variable. It's part of the syntax of the `$<CONFIG:x>` generator expression. `DCONFIG=Release` sets a variable, unrelated to the genex. The genex is based on the "current configuration being generated." For single-config generators, that will be the value of `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE`. For multi-config generators, it will be each configuration from `CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES` in turn as they are generated.

Answer (score 4):

Expressions like `$<...>` are [generator exressions](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html), introduced in CMake 2.8. The main feature of these expressions is that they are evaluated at build time, not at configuration time, like normal CMake variables.

Your particular expression

```
$<$<CONFIG:Debug>:Release>
```

expands to "Release" if `Debug` configuration is in use.